# Prove m ≤ n -> k ≤ l -> m + k ≤ n + l in Agda

Tags: agda, theorem-proving

I want to prove

```
{m n k l : ℕ} -> m ≤ n -> k ≤ l -> m + k ≤ n + l
```

in Agda.
I can prove `m + k ≤ m + l` by the following code

```
add≤ : {m n : ℕ} -> (k : ℕ) -> m ≤ n -> k + m ≤ k + n
add≤ zero exp = exp
add≤ (suc k) exp = s≤s (add≤ k exp)
```

Since I can prove `m + k ≤ m + l`, I want to prove `m + l ≤ n + l`. If I can do that, I will use `≤-trans : Transitive _≤_` which I have already defined. 

Can I prove `m + l ≤ n + l` with `m ≤ n, k ≤ l`? Or, Should I have to change the plan to use `≤-trans`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply

```
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.Nat.Properties

le : {m n k l : ℕ} -> m ≤ n -> k ≤ l -> m + k ≤ n + l
le {n = n}  z≤n    q = ≤-steps n q
le         (s≤s p) q = s≤s (le p q)
```

Comment: I could understand your answer! Thank you!

Comment: For anyone wondering: it works because `_+_` is defined by induction on its first argument and pattern-matching on the `m ≤ n` proof reveals the head constructor of `m` (and `n` in the second case) thus allowing `m + k` and `n + l` to compute.